# Kinect Face tracking on a non UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I am able to track the face when using all the streams (color,depth,skeleton) on the main UI thread. But when I wish to do all the kinect processing on a separate thread, which i do as follows:

```
kinectThread = new Thread(getKinectSensorData);

public void getKinectSensorData()
    {
            sensor.AllFramesReady += new EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>(sensor_AllFramesReady); 
    }
```

My program crashes at the following line with the error shown bellow:

```
faceFrame = newfacetracker.Track(sensor.ColorStream.Format, colorPixelData,
                                       sensor.DepthStream.Format, depthPixelData, currentSkeleton);
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.FaceTracking.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'System.__ComObject' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.FaceTracking.IFTImage'. This operation
>   failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the
>   interface with IID '{1A00A7BC-C217-11E0-AC90-0024811441FD}' failed due
>   to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

The colorstream, depthstream and skeletonstream all work fine however, the program could never pass the newfacetracker.Track line of code. Is it not possible to run the face tracking on a non-UI thread? Please advise me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `streamType.OpenNextFrame(int)` calls?  I ran into a similar issue when working with a depth stream and a skeleton stream.

Comment: No, basically I am using the general event based approach like:
using (ColorImageFrame colorImageFrame = c.OpenColorImageFrame())
Actually, depth and color streams work well except the face tracker. Do you recommend switching to the "polling" strategy? I dont know how would that work, since there is no sample code available using the polling technique. Why does the face tracker give out this error when processed on a non-UI thread?

Comment: How did you solve this issue in your case when using the streamType.OpenNextFrame(int) calls?

Comment: I stopped using it.  I was using Skeleton and Depth data, requesting depth data from the skeleton frame ready callback.  I switch out to just record what I needed from the skeleton in that callback and then dealt with the depth data in the depth frame event callback.

Comment: It is possible to use the face tracking API on a separate thread. I am doing exactly that. However I am using the C++ API.